# Recursively defining a list of monadic random numbers: most idiomatic Haskell and analogous to pure code

Tags: list, haskell, recursion, random, monads

I am trying to recursively make a list of random numbers that uses the previous value to get the next (so recursion is required instead of map or fold, and also I prefer to make it explicit unless map/foldr makes it ridiculously simple in comparison).

Using a pure PRNG this is very straightforward and idiomatic, in my opinion (puregaussian uses System.Random to generate a normal variate and has type `puregaussian :: System.Random.RandomGen t => t -> Double -> Double -> (Double, t)`).

```
purecurse :: System.Random.RandomGen t => t -> Double -> [Double] -> [Double]
purecurse gen current [] = []
purecurse gen current (x:xs) = let (rand, gen2) = puregaussian gen 0 1
                                   next = current + rand
                               in current:purecurse gen2 next xs
```

Unfortunately, pure PRNGs don't seem do be as well developed in Haskell as the monadic ones, so I want to do the same thing using a library like random-fu or mwc-probability, and the solutions I found to work are either unidiomatic, not as concise, or both.

Here's a solution using do notation that works, and why I'm not satisfied with it:

```
import Control.Monad.Primitive
import System.Random.MWC.Probability

recurse :: PrimMonad m => Gen (PrimState m) -> [Double] -> [Double] -> m [Double]
recurse gen history@(current:_) [] = return history
recurse gen history@(current:_) (x:xs) = do
                                         rand <- (sample (normal 0 1) gen)
                                         let next = current + rand
                                         recurse gen (next:history) xs
```

First of all I would rather use `>>=` than do notation, but I couldn't find a way of binding the `rand` variable that has type `m Double` and then lifting it to get `m [Double]` at the end case. There doesn't seem to be a lot of documentation (that I could find) or examples on how to do something like that.
I thought maybe it would be necessary to nest the `(>>=)` operators, but that could make the function extremely complicated or unreadable. If that is the tradeoff, maybe do notation is just cleaner, but I didn't manage to make even that work and would like to know how to.

Second, the function requires the entire list to be passed on at each call, and gives the list back in reverse (and just switching `next` and `history` breaks it).

So. I would like to be able to pass the initial state and a list to recurse over that returns a monadic list of values.

The main question I would like help with is: is there a Haskell idiomatic way of writing such a recursion of monadic values resulting in a monadic list that is similar to the structure of a pure function?

Comment: What is the purpose of the input list? You never use its elements (`x`) in these examples. And you can write your `do`-notation version with `>>=` if you want with the standard desugaring: `sample (normal 0 1) gen >>= \rand -> let next = current + rand in recurse gen (next : history) xs`, or omitting the `let` binding, `sample (normal 0 1) gen >>= \rand -> recurse gen (current + rand : history) xs`.

Comment: You're right the x values are not actually used, they may be in a different version of this function, and I often prefer that to a countdown to 0 as edge case. The desugaring makes sense, and it works, but I guess there is some odd structure with placing the return that is not as intuitive. I still need to find a way of doing away with the history@ construct, but that should be easier that the first part. Thanks.

Comment: Related: "Building a list in a monad" https://www.joachim-breitner.de/blog/620-Constructing_a_list_in_a_Monad

Comment: There's nothing "impure" about monads; they simply allow you to abstract away the explicit handling of the generator between calls to `purecurse`. The notion that monads are impure stems from the fact that one usually learns about monads by working with IO actions. For example, `getLine :: IO String` is an IO *action*, but `putStrLn :: String -> IO ()` is a *pure* function that returns an IO action. The `>>=` operator is a pure function that creates a new IO action, e.g., `getLine >>= putStrLn :: IO ()`.

Comment: @chepner yes, I realize that, the point is not about the function being pure or not, but how to use translate/adapt a typical recursive function to one using monads. Thanks.

Comment: @JonPurdy I think you reply is half of the answer I need. I managed to write it without the `@history` construct, that's the other half of the answer, I guess: `recurse' gen _ [] = return []; recurse' gen current (x:xs) = do
  rand  <- sample (normal 0 1) gen
  let next = current + rand
  future <- recurse' gen next xs
  return (next:future)`
but didn't manage to desugar it in a way similar to what you did. Putting the two things together would be the exact answer to the question I had, if it's at al possible. In any case thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The main question I would like help with is: is there a Haskell idiomatic way of writing such a recursion of monadic values resulting in a monadic list that is similar to the structure of a pure function?

You can do it in two steps. Have your recursive function return a list of "monadic actions", then compose / sequence those actions.

Lets consider a simpler but analogous function to yours, for ease of presentation. Instead of randomness lets consider input. The list you recourse over is there for size only (content is ignored) so lets just use an integer.

```
rc ::  Int -> [Double] -> IO [Double]
rc 0 h        = return h
rc n h@(cr:_) = do rand <- readLn :: IO Double
                   let nx = cr + rand
                   rc (n-1)(nx:h)
```

Here is a similar alternative that works the way you wants

```
rc' ::  Int -> Double -> IO [Double]
rc' 0 cr = return []
rc' n cr = do rand <- readLn :: IO Double
              let nx = cr + rand
              xs   <- rc' (n-1) nx
              return (nx : xs)
```

And here without do notation

```
rc'' ::  Int -> Double -> IO [Double]
rc'' 0 cr = return []
rc'' n cr = (readLn :: IO Double) >>= (\rand -> 
              let nx = cr + rand 
              in (rc'' (n-1) nx) >>= (\xs ->
                 return (nx : xs)))
```

In any case, another thing you can do is abstract away pieces of code, rather than have a monolithic presentation.

In each step you require the current value to generate a new one. So a step is a function of type `Double -> IO Double`. And this is a pretty neat type, fundamental in the world of monads. You can bind values to a step via `x >>= step` or compose two steps with `step1 >=> step2`. So lets go with it.

```
step :: Double -> IO Double
step cr = do rand <- readLn :: IO Double
             return (cr + rand)
```

It's very easy to understand. You 'generate' a number, add the current one and return the result. And you want to do `n` such steps, so make a list of steps.

```
steps :: Int -> [Double -> IO Double]
steps n = replicate n step
```

Now you can choose how to combine them. For instance it would be very natural to fold a list of steps with `>=>`. You would get this,

```
runSteps :: Int -> Double -> IO Double 
runSteps n = foldr (>=>) return (steps n)
```

It's close to what you want but only returns the final result, rather than accumulate the generated values at each step. Below is a (restricted) type of `(>=>)` and the type of the operator `(*=>)` we want.

```
(>=>) :: Monad m => (a -> m a) -> (b -> m  a)  -> a -> m  a
(*=>) :: Monad m => (a -> m a) -> (a -> m [a]) -> a -> m [a]
```

The definition is,

```
(*=>) :: Monad m => (a -> m a) -> (a -> m [a]) -> a -> m [a]
(*=>) ac uc c = do x  <- ac c
                   xs <- uc x
                   return (x:xs)
```

I actually think this encapsulates the bit you didn't particularly like. Now we abstracted it away to this isolated piece of code. Even away from the recursive calls. And finally we just fold to execute the steps.

```
execSteps :: Int -> Double -> IO [Double] 
execSteps n = foldr (*=>) (\x -> return []) (steps n)
```

This function differs from the original one in the initial input being a `Double` rather than a `[Double]`. But this is the type that makes sense. You'd just be passing a single wrapped double in the original function. And it accumulates the elements in the 'right' order as you requested.

Comment: I tried to make a sequence of what I think you are calling "monadic actions" to bind results to `m Double` variables, but I couldn't turn that into `m [Double]` the way I thought I could.
I'm assuming sequence would "just work" on a list of monads  so I could bind that to `m [Double]`, but I'm still missing that previous step.
I'm no sure that would be the closest solution to the pure function structure, but in any case a full example would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I edited my reply to provide an example. I had explicitly mentioned "sequence" but indeed your function can't be sequenced in that way. In any case, the is the same (which you may or may not like). You can abstract various bits of your code away, which results in some actions that you need to sequence / compose. The idea being that this should isolate away the bit or bits you find more confusing, and the rest should be easily relatable to non-monadic strategies.

Comment: Thanks for elaborating. It's not clear to me that this implementation accounts for the dependence of each new state on the previous state, not just the accumulator and the new "random" value, but admittedly it may be my fault in not understanding the monadic operators `>=>` and `*=>`. I'm not an experienced Haskeller and rarely go beyond `>>=` and `>>` with monads.
Also I think monolithic recursion is very transparent, so I was hoping there could be an analogous way of doing that. However, it may well be that this is more idiomatic, but I don't really like it. In any case thanks for the help.

Comment: OK, so edited the answer to include a monolithic alternative to yours. I suppose you  might prefer that. I do believe it should be very useful to go through the modular code though. In particular because the monolithic version implicitly does the work of (*=>). And you might understand that better in isolation. Also the modular code gives you the opportunity to look at the version with (>=>) that just returns the last result, which is simpler and an intermediate step to understand how this all works. Also note (>=>) is very close to (>>=), it's just defined by (f >=> g) x = f x >>= g

Comment: The `rc` function is half of what I wanted, the same as my comment above, the other part was using `>>=` instead of do, but I didn't seem to desugar that multiline statement correctly, if it's possible. That would be the exact answer I'm looking for.

Comment: Edited to include a version with `>>=` instead of do notation.

Comment: Sorry for all the trouble, that was exactly the structure I was looking for but couldn't figure out. These parentheses get pretty funky when nesting `>>=` operators. Obrigado.

Comment: No worries! Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

> is there a Haskell idiomatic way of writing such a recursion of
>   monadic values resulting in a monadic list that is similar to the
>   structure of a pure function

Usually, when need apply a monadic values to a pure function, [Applicative](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#t:Applicative) operator, such as `<$>`, `<*>` may be helpful.

In particular, for list construction, it is often apply operator `(:)` in recursive way to build a list, like

```
f [] = []
f (x:xs) = x : f xs
```

in prefix way:

```
(:) x (f xs)
```

However, (:) is pure function, not accept monadic value by default, but the good new is, every data type which is instance of Monad, it also be an instance of Applicative. with help of Applicative operator mentioned above, monadic value can be applied to pure function without any change. For example,

```
(:) <$> (pure x) <*> (pure .f) xs
```

will return a monadic List instead of pure list.

Return to your question, personally, I think your solution in question is already almost a  idiomatic way to do that (since it is simple and readable) except always append `next random value` at the head of `history`.

As you said, `the list back in reverse` and worse, when the `history` list has old random value already, it is inconvenient to find out which is new add to it.

To solve it, it can be modified slightly as:

```
recurse :: PrimMonad m => Gen (PrimState m) -> [Double] -> [Double] -> m [Double]
recurse gen history [] = return history
recurse gen history (x:xs) = do rand <- (sample (normal 0 1) gen)
                                let next = (last history) + rand
                                recurse gen (history ++ [next]) xs
```

It make sense, if the last element of history is the newest random value.

However, the different between `(:)` and `(++)` is: `(:)` is O(1), but (++) is O(N), where the N is the length of history list. (and `last history` is also O(N) instead of O(1)).

To archive an efficient solution, a helper function may need to introduce, say, `newHistory`, to construct a new list of random value as:

```
newHistory::PrimMonad m=>Gen(PrimState m)->m Double->[Double]->m [Double]
newHistory _ _ []             = return []
newHistory gen current (x:xs) = let next = (+) <$> current <*> sample (normal 0 1) gen
                                in  (:) <$> next <*> newHistory gen next xs
```

As said before, with help of Applicative operator, the syntax look like pure function, except apply function in prefix way and use Applicative operator.

And then append back to the original `history` list as:

```
(++) <$> pure history <*> newHistory gen (pure $ last history) xs
```

And the Applicative version of `recurse` function look like:

```
recurse2::PrimMonad m=>Gen(PrimState m)->[Double]->[Double]->m [Double]
recurse2 gen history xs = 
    (++) <$> pure history <*> newHistory gen (pure $ last history) xs

    where newHistory::PrimMonad m=>Gen(PrimState m)->m Double->[Double]->m [Double]
          newHistory _ _ []         = return []
          newHistory gen current (x:xs) = 
            let next = (+) <$> current <*> sample (normal 0 1) gen
            in  (:) <$> next <*> newHistory gen next xs
```

Comment: Thanks. I think applicative can be an alternative to monads here, I will have to take a closer look at what comes out of using it, but I want to keep it as readable as possible even for non-Haskellers, and applicative always looks kind of alien to many people (`>>=` too, to be fair). Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

In situations like this, I usually jump straight to using a streaming library with a suitably list-like interface, like [streaming](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/streaming-0.2.2.0). They allow a more natural translation from pure code to monadic, and have the added benefit that you aren't required to construct/consume all of the results at once, but instead incrementally, just as with pure lists.

I'm not sure what `purecurse` is doing, but it could be written as

```
import           Streaming
import qualified Streaming.Prelude as S

recurse :: PrimMonad m 
        => Gen (PrimState m) 
        -> Double 
        -> [Double] 
        -> Stream (Of Double) m ()
recurse gen current [] = 
    return ()
recurse gen current (x:xs) =
    S.yield current *> -- (*>) and (>>) work like concatenation for pure lists
    lift (sample (normal 0 1) gen) >>= \rand -> 
    recurse gen (current + rand) xs
```

Or, more naturally using do-notation, as:

```
recurse :: PrimMonad m 
        => Gen (PrimState m) 
        -> Double 
        -> [Double] 
        -> Stream (Of Double) m ()
recurse gen current [] = 
    return ()
recurse gen current (x:xs) = 
    do S.yield current -- (*>) and (>>) work like concatenation for pure lists
       rand <- lift $ sample (normal 0 1) gen
       recurse gen (current + rand) xs
```

Now you can use function like [`S.take`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/streaming-0.2.2.0/docs/Streaming-Prelude.html#v:take) to generate/extract only parts of the result. If you want to get the whole list, you can use [`S.toList_`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/streaming-0.2.2.0/docs/Streaming-Prelude.html#v:toList_).

Comment: `pureceurse` is a typical recursively defined list where each item is defined at a step and joined to the previous ones with `:`, then appending `:[]` in the end to actually make it into a list.
I wanted a monadic version of that in terms of basic monad operators, not higher level libraries, and not even do notation, if possible. In any case thanks for the help, I'll check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue seems to lie with do-notation and monads. You're assuming there's much more magic going on than there actually is: [learning how the desugaring works](http://www.haskellforall.com/2014/10/how-to-desugar-haskell-code.html) will help you out here.

Anyway, let's try and convert the non-monadic version into the monadic one step-by-step. First, the type signature:

```
recurse :: PrimMonad m => Gen (PrimState m) -> Double -> [Double] -> m [Double]
```

I'm not sure why you had `[Double]` as the second parameter in your version: we want to change as little as possible from the original. The first clause, then:

```
purecurse gen current [] = []
-- Goes to:
recurse gen current [] = return []
```

Again, we're changing as little as possible: no effects were happening in this clause in your pure code, so no effects should be happening here, either. You got the next two lines right:

```
purecurse gen current (x:xs) = let (rand, gen2) = puregaussian gen 0 1
                                   next = current + rand
-- Goes to:
recurse gen current (x:xs) = do rand <- (sample (normal 0 1) gen)
                                let next = current + rand
```

But the last one tripped you up. Ideally, we would write:

```
in current:purecurse gen2 next xs
-- Goes to:
current:recurse gen next xs
```

But it doesn't work! What's more, you get a confusing error:

```
• Couldn't match type ‘Double’ with ‘[Double]’
  Expected type: m [Double]
    Actual type: [Double]
```

This is probably what led you down the wrong path. The issue has nothing to do with the lists: it's to do with the `m` (the encapsulating monad). When you write `current : xs`, `xs` has to be a list: in this example, it's actually a `m [Double]`, or a list wrapped in the monad. There's two ways to solve the problem (which are both equivalent). We could *unwrap* the list, using do notation again:

```
rest <- recurse gen next xs
return (current : rest)
```

Or we could *lift* the function `current :` to work inside the monad:

```
fmap (current:) (recurse gen next xs)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I do understand how desugaring works, and the do-notation function is doing what is expected. I am indeed having trouble with the interaction of the bind operator and recursion, that's what I needed help with, but thanks for your time.